# SELECT coluna tipo DATE por HH24:mm:ss

Tags: sql, oracle, select, data

Olá, tenho 2 campos do tipo DATE, conforme o snippet abaixo:

```
  ...hr_inicio                 DATE         NOT NULL,
     hr_fim                    DATE         NOT NULL, ...
```

E estou com a necessidade de consultar esses campos usando apenas os valores referentes à horário **HH24:mm:ss**, exemplo: 10:00:00

Deste modo gostaria de realizar o meu select passando como parâmetros da cláusula where a hora, minuto e segundo. Para trazer todas as datas que possuem o horário de inicio 10:00:00 e horário fim 12:00:00 conforme na imagem abaixo.

[image: Campos do tipo HR_INICIO e HR_FIM]

*Estou usando o Oracle SQL*

---

PS: Já tentei usar a seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE 
HR_INICIO = TO_DATE('10:00:00','hh24:mi:ss') AND
HR_FIM    = TO_DATE('12:00:00','hh24:mi:ss')
```

Mas não foi eficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver e trazer os registros usando o seguinte código:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA
  WHERE TO_char(HR_INICIO,'hh24:mi:ss') = TO_char(TO_DATE('10:00:00','hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24:mi:ss')
  AND TO_char(HR_FIM,'hh24:mi:ss') = TO_char(TO_DATE('13:00:00','hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Acredito que esse exemplo possa te ajudar:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, hire_date
  FROM employees
 WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM
TO_DATE(hire_date, 'DD-MON-RR')) = 10
```

Segue [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639) da documentação.
Em SQL SERVER eu faço:

```
SELECT *
  FROM @TABLE
 WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DataEntrada) = 10 --Para hora inicial 10h
   AND DATEPART(HOUR, DataSaida) = 18 --Para hora final 18h
```

Consegui a informação de acordo com a equivalência do DATEPART (nesse caso o EXTRACT)).
Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,